# Python requests post fails when using json.dump

Tags: python, json

Using `requests` to post JSON to a web service. Typing out the JSON like this works:

```
response = requests.post('https://ws.foo.net/search',
json=({
  "filters": [
    {
    "filters": [
        {
        "field": "type",
        "type": "EQ",
        "value": "THING"
        }
        ]
    },
                    {
    "filters": [
        {
        "field": "responseCode",
        "type": "EQ",
        "value": "301"
        },
        {
        "field": "responseCode",
        "type": "EQ",
        "value": "302"
        }
        ]
    },
                    {
    "filters": [
        {
        "field": "State",
        "type": "EQ",
        "value": "CONFIRMED"
        }
        ]
    }
]
}), auth=('name', 'password'))
```

I want to use variables in the JSON so constructing that from a dictionary using `json.dumps`.

Below produces a 400 error:

> Could not read JSON: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, classcom.linkco.ws.v1.model.V1SearchQuery] from JSON String; no single-String constructor/factory method

```
import json
import requests


jsonObject = {'filters': [{'filters': [{'field': 'type','type': 'EQ','value': 'WEB_SITE'}]},{'filters': [{'field': 'name','type': 'EQ','value': 'something'}]},{'filters': [{'field': 'State','type': 'EQ','value': 'CONFIRMED'}]}]}

response = requests.post('https://ws.foo.net/search', json=json.dumps(jsonObject), auth=('name', 'password'))


print json.dumps(jsonObject)
print '----'
print response.text
```

I'm printing the `json.dumps(jsonObject)` to check and it produces valid JSON and works if copied to a REST client I'm using - it's good (well - it's probably not for a reason I've failed to find).

Answer (score 1):

A small bug is causing you the trouble

```
response = requests.post('https://ws.foo.net/search', 
                         json=jsonObject # was json.dumps(jsonObject), 
                         auth=('name', 'password'))
```

This should work fine

See, the request package will convert the python dict to Json (not you ;))

Comment: That did it. Hugely appreciated. Thank you.